# Cannot CREATE DATABASE After Enabling Sentry

Tags: apache-sentry

I am trying to create a database after enabling sentry on my cluster and kerberos is not setup yet, i am getting the error:

```
 0: jdbc:hive2://votlbdcd32:10000> create database test123;
 Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException No   
 valid  privileges
 User sec_admin does not have privileges for CREATEDATABASE
 The required privileges: Server=votlabcd123.xxx.xxxx.com->action=*;   
 (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I tried to run teh following command and didn't help me much

```
grant all on server server1 to role role_sec_admin_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to run the following command with the correct server name

grant all on server server1 to role role_sec_admin_all;

my server name was 'server1.example.com'

I updated my grant statement as given below and then it worked
grant all on server `server1.example.com` to role role_sec_admin_all;